# SQL ON clause v WHERE clause (different results)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the DDL below:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable(id int, [name] varchar(30))
CREATE TABLE TestTable2(id int, [name] varchar(30))

INSERT INTO TestTable (id,[name]) values (1,'')
INSERT INTO TestTable (id,[name]) values (2,'Martin')

INSERT INTO TestTable2 (id,[name]) values (1,null)
INSERT INTO TestTable2 (id,[name]) values (2,'Martin')

select TestTable.* from TestTable
LEFT JOIN TestTable2 
ON TestTable.id=TestTable2.id 
and TestTable.[name]= TestTable2.[Name] and NOT (TestTable.[name] ='' and TestTable2.[name] is null)
where testtable2.id is null
```

The SELECT returns one row and I would expect it to return none.  The reason I would expect it to return none is the same reason the SQL statement below returns none:

```
select TestTable.* from TestTable
LEFT JOIN TestTable2 
ON TestTable.id=TestTable2.id 
and TestTable.[name]= TestTable2.[Name] 
where testtable2.id is null and NOT (TestTable.[name] ='' and TestTable2.[name] is null)
```

Why does the first SQL statement return one row?  The ON clause should filer out those records with this criteria:  NOT (TestTable.[name] ='' and TestTable2.[name] is null).  The one row returned contains this criteria.  Why?

Answer (score 5):

A `LEFT JOIN` will return all rows from the left table unless they are filtered out by the `WHERE` criteria, your first query `WHERE` criteria excludes 1 row, the `WHERE` in your second query excludes both rows.

Update:  A popular reference for understanding Joins is:
**[Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)**

`ON` is used to define how the tables will be joined together, `WHERE` to limit the results. In the case of an `INNER JOIN` they both limit results, with an `OUTER JOIN` the difference between them becomes appreciable.

Comment: Agreed.  I just had to deal with this myself at work.  Add a where filter that checks the left join part, and it essentially gets treated like an inner join, as it has to meet the criteria of the filter.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought the ON clause decided what appeared in the LEFT table (I am obviously wrong).  Is there any documentation I can be referred to? +1.